# Pulley question - why is considering the system equation wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

So I have done this Physics pulley question (attached).

In the setup, you have two particles, connected by a light inextensible string passing over a smooth pulley, with one particle at rest on a smooth table and the other hanging freely. The system is then released from rest.

Now I have answered the question, but the mark scheme points out that:

"Use of the whole system equation $0.6g = 1.4a$ cannot score all the marks, except a mark for it being a correct equation"

Why is this approach not valid for solving the problem?

[image]

Comment: Why do you get the correct answer here using this supposedly incorrect method?

Comment: If this is an AP test question, note that your answer isn't wrong ... it's incomplete.  You must demonstrate that you know all of the underlying concepts involved, which requires starting from beginning concepts and developing the problem to the final equation.  Your goal should be to match the AP rubric as closely as possible, but you must anticipate what the rubric will say because it doesn't exist at the time that you take the AP test.  Also note - your problem is a version of an Atwood machine, and it should be developed this way.

Comment: @DavidWhite Is correct. The rubric is not saying it is incorrect. It is saying it just doesn't show sufficient work for the grading. Because of this I have voted to close this question as "opinion based" since it is more of a question about grading preferences.

Comment: @AaronStevens well it’s not opinion based I don’t think, I was also unsure why it was incomplete!

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove, I'll post an answer of how I would solve this problem.  And note that I taught AP Physics C for 10 years, and I have released rubrics going back to 1974, so I mostly know what such rubrics are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us just suppose that the two masses were just connected by a string and pulled by a horizontal force on one of the masses. There, you can consider them to be a single system of masses, because the net internal forces cancel out.

You get the acceleration of the centre of mass, which in that case is the acceleration of the blocks. But in this case, if you make it into one system, you will notice that

1) the net internal forces don't cancel out

2) The acceleration of the Centre of mass is not the same as that of the individual masses.

But, as you have noticed, you are getting the correct answer. This is because the forces on the bodies are along the direction of motion, and it gives the appearance of the first case discussed here.

Answer (score 2):

There are two objects in this problem, and acceleration and forces are involved.  This means that a complete problem development should involve the following:

1) Draw a correct free body diagram of each object, showing forces on each object, but not showing accelerations

2) Use Newton's 2nd law to develop an equation that applies to each object, where each equation has a term for the tension in the string

3) Note that the acceleration of each object is the same, and set up a system of two equations (one equation for each object)

4) Add both equations together to eliminate "T", which is the tension in the string

5) Algebraically manipulate the resulting equation to separate "a", which is the acceleration of the system

6) Lastly, use this final equation to substitute values, and calculate a correct answer, with correct units

This means that the question is actually testing your knowledge of free body diagrams, Newton's 2nd law, the concept that both objects have the same acceleration, and your expertise in eliminating variable "T" and separating variable "a".  Your answer was far too brief to show this work, and while you demonstrated that you can work this problem "in your head", the rubric and the graders cannot grade what is "in your head".  Thus, your work was incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider both the balls as one system, then should  not you also consider the normal force on the ball P? You just happened to get the correct equation because the tension is same on both the balls.

The main problem is that you cannot consider the two balls as a single system because they are not having the same acceleration. Though, the magnitude of the acceleration is same for both the balls, the direction is not. Therefore, I think, it's not the right way.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this provides some insight. Looking for a slightly more assured answer, but will accept if that doesn't arrive :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think the marking scheme want us to consider forces acting along both axis x and y.

Comment: That's true, but I want to understand why we can't consider the whole body to get the equation $1.4a = 0.6g$ and why it gives the correct answer also

Comment: i think in this question there is no friction on object P which make T=0.8 a , if there would have been some friction we could not consider the whole body equation and the friction just acts on object P and not Q and ofcourse as abhinav pointed out the directions are different